# Checking for Uniqueness of a entity properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In entity framework code migrations i realize that unique indexes can be added to columns.But when an attempt is made to insert a duplicate value you get back error message from the data based  in an SQL Exception wrapped in  UpdateException.
This is not very user friendly to display to a user.

Is it best to query the database for the existence of the value  and display a user friend error message?

If not, Is there a more intuitive way of  doing uniqueness checks and displaying a user friendly error message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/686y883x.aspx) in InnerException(s) of UpdateException. SqlException has a [Number Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) which addresses the cause of exception. SqlException also provides more detail about the error with other properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  Mehmet.  I am thinking about unique indices on the columns in the database and also thinking of  implementing Ivalidation and checking the database if a duplicate value exists and  yield a validation exception if necessary. Is this best way to do this by querying data context in an entity class?